# Error on inserting data to InfluxDB

Tags: insert, influxdb

I am new to influxdb.

By learning from the official site of influx, I have entered the line

```
curl -i -XPOST "http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb" --data-binary "cpu_load_short,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.64 1434055562000000000"
```

but I am getting error :
invalid character:"//" looking for beginning of value

any solution ?

Comment: Something is wrong with your curl syntax, although nothing leaps out at me. Try using double-quotes to surround the URL. Please paste in the actual -i information if possible.

Comment: @backettsean I am using " " double quotes only.

Comment: I think it must be a syntax problem, not anything fundamentally broken. Since your example shows single-quotes, I would request that you paste in the exact curl command and the output, so there's no ambiguity as to the syntax you are using.